# Arguments before a colon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, react-redux

I'm trying to pass an argument to a function in Javascript. However, the argument **column** is being interpreted as a literal string as opposed to an argument to the function. This is due to the colon directly following the argument **column**:

```
    update(column, selected) {
          var cols = {...this.props.columns, column: selected}
          this.props.dispatch(updateColumns({type: "UPDATE_COLUMNS", cols}))
    }
```

I've tried using **arguments[0]** instead of **column** but then I am told arguments is a reserved word in strict mode. Any idea how I can get read this value as an argument as opposed to a string?

Comment: `[column]` instead of just `column` - it'll only work in newer browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern JavaScript environments, object initializer syntax allows for expressions to be evaluated on the left side of the property initialization:

```
update(column, selected) {
      var cols = {...this.props.columns, [column]: selected}
      this.props.dispatch(updateColumns({type: "UPDATE_COLUMNS", cols}))
}
```

The square brackets mean that the expression inside should be evaluated, and the result should be used as the property name.

In older environments, you'd have to do it in a separate statement, but since you're already using spread syntax I'd guess you're not concerned with that.